# How to play an inline video in Phonegap on Android without user interaction?

Tags: javascript, android, html, video, cordova

I'm creating a Phonegap application with embedded video using the HTML5  tag.

The video loads and plays fine. The only problem is that it requires user interaction. The play script runs fine when I trigger it by clicking a link, but will not work when run using setTimeOut. Is there a way to bypass this limitation?

It only needs to work on one device, and the devices is rooted. So hacks are also welcome ;-)

I don't want to play the video fullscreen, so I cannot use the video plugin.

Android 4.2.2, Phonegap 3.2

Comment: Can you not load video in OnCreate() of your android activity?

Comment: The videos are dynamically added to the page. Also I'm not sure how to use OnCreate :-)

Comment: I guess you are using android phonegap app, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The javascript app downloads some JSON that contains the video URL, then downloads the video. After that HTML is added dynamically and the video should play.

Comment: So basically you will be having android java class that will be extending Activity.There are overridden methods of activity and one such method is "onCraete()". In that method you can load your videos.

Comment: Thanks! I believe the inline HTML5 video is not a separate Android Activity. Will that still work?

Comment: Can you please show some code. That will give better idea.

Comment: I add the video using this javascript (jQuery) code:

`code`
$('#elementid' ).html( '<video id="example_video_1" controls preload="auto" width="720" height="404"
      poster="white.png"
      autoplay
      autobuffer
      data-setup="{}">
    <source src="file:///mnt/sdcard/screen_files/1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>');
`/code`

After adding, I try to start it using: 
`code`
$("#example_video_1")[0].play();
`/code`
That works only if I click a link to trigger the code, running it from setTimeOut will fail.